# How to StartActivity from class in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-intent

Im trying to start an activity from another class in Android, and im getting this error message

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:118)

This is where the crash happends

```
class LoginAuthticate : Activity() { 

    fun loginUser(view: LoginActivity) {

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
        .addOnCompleteListener(view) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me guess: somewhere in your code, you have `LoginAuthenticate()` to create an instance of this "activity", right? If so, get rid of that. Only the framework can create activity instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
view.startActivity(Intent(view, MainActivity::class.java))
```

Thank you all for your suggestion and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
startActivity(Intent(this@Activity, MainActivity::class.java))
```

Like below

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
    .addOnCompleteListener(view) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
          startActivity(Intent(this@LoginAuthticate, MainActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work got this error :     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:152)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help...

```
if (task.isSuccessful) {
startActivity(Intent(this@LoginAuthticate, MainActivity::class.java))
}
```

Comment: It didn't work got this error :      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:152)